# why search engine does not crawl my site?

Tags: seo, search-engine

I've had a robots.txt and now is already removed, and I've tried to submit URL to search engine and when I search my site on search engine, there is no result on the page.

How to appear the site on search engine?

Thanks.

Comment: depends on the search engine, give this a read http://www.google.com/webmasters/

Comment: great resources, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use google webmaster tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) it can help you to figure out some problems.
Also I would recommend to read search engine optimization starter guide from google http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

p.s. SEO always needs a time and you can't get the results immediately.